# How to force Angular 2 [(ngModel)] change after changing input value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I am trying to replace Japanese half-width characters to full-width characters.

ｳ -> ウ

So whenever a user types in half width, we have to convert to full width automatically.

Obvious solution would be to design a directive to change the ngModel on keypress. But we have a huge codebase and I was thinking maybe with `@Hostlistener` would be able to change the value.

```
@HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event) {
   if (event.target.hasAttribute('type')
       && event.target.attributes['type'].value === 'text') {

    event.target.value = this.changeToFullWidth(event, event.target.value);

  }
}
```

However with this `[(ngModel)]` is always one character behind and I know this is because I am touching the HTML element directly.

Is there a way to do this ? Or will I have to go harder approach of adding directive to each input tag in whole project?

Comment: Are you using NG 1.x?

Comment: Nope sorry .. Angular 2

Comment: have you tried modifying the data property the ngModel is bound to directly? (you would need access to that property - so most likely you'd need to be within that controller.

`this.inputModelValue = 'your new value'`

Comment: I could do that but then I would have to go to each `input` in the codebase and manually put this function in .. I was trying to implement a global replacer which can work for whole application

Comment: I'm not real hip to the newer NG's - but it does seem that trying to modify the DOM value directly would not trigger a model update - unless you then triggered a focus/blur. or something else - which generally seems hacky.

Comment: Yeah I tried focus/blur thing .. but ngModel changes on only "change" I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I was able to trigger model change following way:

```
targetElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
```

But found out that it doesn't work in Edge for CKEditor.

For that we can use the directive and model service

```
...
constructor(
        ...
        private model:NgModel,
        ...
    ){
...
onInputChange($event){
...
   this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.changeText(modelValue));
...
}
```

Comment: The dispatchEvent solution worked for me, but dispatchEvent only takes one parameter, so I passed in the event without the {bubbles: true} param.

Comment: To add to the comment I just made. I realize the parenthesis is in the wrong place in your code. It should be dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }))

Comment: Nice solution, really helpful in automation :)